# Hiding data loaded in a filtered jQuery listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile list view that loads `<li>` elements from a php file on the server into a listview. I have set this list filterable. However, what i want is that when the page loads the list should not appear. I tried `data-filter-reveal="true"` but this doesnot work when the page first loads. Here is my code structure:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="aa" data-filter-placeholder="Search ...">
<!-- Data loaded from server here -->
</ul>

<script>
$(function(){
$.get(
"file.php",
function(data){
    $('#aa').html(data)
    .listview('refresh');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just `$("#aa").hide()`?

Comment: yep i can but then how do i `.show()` when i am typing inside the search bar

Comment: You should also refresh the filterable widget. $('#aa').filterable( "refresh" );

Comment: @ezanker it works perfectly now with Niazipan solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment as I don't have 50 reputation, but:

How are you adding the `<li>` elements from your php file?

Are you manually adding the `ui-screen-hidden` css class to the `<li>` elements, as you add them as that's how jQuery Mobile toggles their visibility during filtering?

EDIT --

In the php file try adding to the `ui-screen-hidden` class to the `<li>` elements.

```
<li class="ui-screen-hidden">
<?php 
  echo="The data you're writting in"; 
?>
</li>
```

Comment: yep this does hide the list but when i try to search the search entries too are hidden

Comment: One way could be that my search bar is already filled with text like Search... then the user could erase this first and type the search entry. In this it works. But i don't how to have a pre filled search bar